# Why does sometimes selenium locate objects and sometimes no?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Good morning,
I am trying to automatize simple online procedure: go to this site http://nvidia-research-mingyuliu.com/gaugan/
Check the little box, update a picture, render it and download it clicking the download button.
I have written my code, which is extremely intuitive and very short, but for some reasons sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.
Sure enough, sometimes python returns the following error:
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="myCheck"]"}

My code is:

```
import selenium
import time

from selenium import webdriver
# Using Chrome to access web
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/Marco/Downloads/chromedriver')

# Open the website
driver.get('http://nvidia-research-mingyuliu.com/gaugan/')
# Select the checkbox
time.sleep(5)
check_box = driver.find_element_by_id('myCheck')
check_box.click()
# Upload File button
element = driver.find_element_by_id("myCheck")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
choose_file = driver.find_element_by_id('segmapfile')
# Send the file location to the button
choose_file.send_keys('/Users/Marco/Desktop/Foto upload/Schermata 2020-10-31 alle 00.07.03.png')
#Locate submit button and click
submit_assignment = driver.find_element_by_id('btnSegmapLoad')
submit_assignment.click()
#render
render_button = driver.find_element_by_id('render')
render_button.click()
#download
save_box = driver.find_element_by_id('save_render')
time.sleep(5)
save_box.click()
```

Why is this happening? How should i solve it?
Thank you

Comment: Try adding a wait before you try to find that element

Comment: Yes, there is a wait in the code. It is time.sleep(5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use explicit waits which wait for something to happen, as opposed to 'time.sleep(5)' which just waits for 5 seconds:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# Using Chrome to access web
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/Marco/Downloads/chromedriver')

# Open the website
driver.get('http://nvidia-research-mingyuliu.com/gaugan/')
# Wait for checkbox to be located
check_box_wait = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'myCheck'))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(check_box_wait)
# Select the checkbox
check_box = driver.find_element_by_id('myCheck')
check_box.click()
```

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't work, it gives the following error: 'raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

TimeoutException'

Comment: Did you try increasing the wait time, ex: ```(driver, 10)``` or ```(driver, 20)``` ? If that doesn't work try using xpath instead of ID.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes it works and sometimes it gives the same error

Comment: Try the edited code. I have better luck with ```presence_of_element_located``` instead of  ```element_to_be_clickable```. I edited the code above to reflect the changes. If this answers your question, please mark as solved.